# Append over existing CSV cell value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, append

So I have been doing searches for 2 days trying to find a solution to this. What I need is to take this preexisting csv file and append certain cells based on user input and Date. The values would be for SA, SI, CS, CBW. I have tried pandas using .append and multiple other work arounds I am at a loss and appreciate any help.

```
with open('morning.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:            
        fieldnames = ['Date','Time','Initials', 'Seymour Well', 'Seymour Dist', 'Baylor Well','Baylor Dist','Train A Hours', 'Train B Hours',
                      'SA', 'SI', 'CS','CBW', 'TAPF', 'TACF','TBPF','TBCF']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        line = csvfile.readline()
        if line != "\n":
            writer.writerow({'Date': slt_19,'Time':slt_16,'Initials':slt_17, 'Seymour Well':slt_2, 'Seymour Dist':slt_3,
                             'Baylor Well':slt_1,'Baylor Dist':slt_4,'Train A Hours':slt_5, 'Train B Hours':slt_6,
                      'SA':slt_7, 'SI':slt_8, 'CS':slt_9,'CBW':slt_10, 'TAPF':slt_11, 'TACF':slt_12,'TBPF':slt_13,'TBCF':slt_14 })
```

my csv file it will be much larger then this updated at least once a day these values i just through in to work with.

```
Date,Time,Initials,Seymour Well,Seymour Dist,Baylor Well,Baylor Dist,Train A Hours,Train B Hours,SA,SI,CS,CBW,TAPF,TACF,TBPF,TBCF
2018-03-01,800,MCS,100,100,100,100,1.0,1.0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

My first intuition would be to extract the desired element in the csvfile and add the user input to it as a string e.g.

```
str1 = 'hot'
str2 = 'dog'
print(str1+str2)
```

However, it's difficult to know if this is the issue you're having. What error are you getting when you attempt to run the code?

Comment: not getting errors i need to have it write the new input over the existing cell and save the file

Comment: all inputs to the original file are user input through line edits but the values i need to change are chemical levels that we refill so if we add chemicals for a day that is already input we would have a negative output the next day when entering the new days data

Comment: Okay, I understand now. I hate to point out the obvious, but have you tried spamwriter.writerow? If so, why did that not work?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: because i need to append a row by searching for it using the date column and only append certain aspects of the row.

Comment: i cant have multiply lines with the same date